# Can't input text in comment textbox on instagram using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram, geckodriver

I found the xpath of the comment box for a said user's Instagram post, and wrote a code, but I'm unable to post a comment there. Here's what I used:

```
com = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
com.click()
com.send_keys('Cool page!')
com.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This is supposed to comment 'cool page!' on the comment box, but it does not. When I manually click in the comment box before this part of the program runs, it works just fine, and fills in 'cool page!' and hits submit, but without manually clicking the comment box, it does nothing. I don't know how I would make it work.

EDIT. HTML code by request: https://pastebin.com/trfkyQ4P
HTML text area:

```
> <textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…"
> class="Ypffh" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height:
> 18px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Can you please share HTML code ?

Comment: please share html structure of this issue for more clarification of this problem.

Comment: html code is now available

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check your xpath.

Try using the below xpath.

```
 //textarea[contains(@aria-label,'Add a comment')]
```

Comment: no luck. I used xpath finder for firefox to find mine, it should work but for some reason the text isn't going into the box. im pretty sure I have the right xpath, its just that the comment isn't going in.